# Extract Zip Artifact as part of Azure App Service Deploy?

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm in the process of setting up a build and release of an asp.net core web app on vsts.

I've the build working with the following tasks:

- Build solution
- dotnet publish
- create artifact of type zip to $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/MyApp_$(Build.BuildId).zip
- publish
  -- artifact path $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/MyApp_$(Build.BuildId).zip
   -- artifact name MyApp_Package

This all works fine...

The release is an "Azure App Service Deploy" task.
The "package or folder" is $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/MyBuild/MyApp_Package
It is "working" sortof in that it is deploying the zip file to the Azure web app but does not extract the files.

How do I get it to extract the zip on the azure web site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are deploying a package (zip), you need to check **Publish using Web Deploy** option and specify the zip file for **Package or folder**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks starain, I had the "publish using Web Deploy" checked. The mistake I made was that I had specified the artifact package folder and not the zip file name. Changing the package or folder from $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/MyBuild/MyApp_Package to 
$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/MyBuild/MyApp_Package/*.zip got the deployment to extract the files. This is a very subtle difference and would be worth updating the documentation to reflect this. Thanks Donal

Comment: I don't see that option in TFS 2018.1 on-prem. I selected the zip file in the release definition and it worked.

Comment: This did not work for me. I ensured Web Deploy was selected here, and it still copies my archive over and never extracts the files. Had to follow @Assassin 's answer

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. However the "Publish using Web Deploy" option has been checked all the time. I also tried the version 2 and 3 of the task.

My solution was to add unzip .zip and rm

[image: Deployment Script example]

Comment: Thanks  for sharing. Very goofy that this is necessary. I did try the Web Deploy selection and that did not work; Web Deploy just copied my .zip over without extracting the contents. Very annoying.