# Remove a DLL from the bin folder in the Build Pipeline

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops, post-build-event

I have the following build script which is not working with Azure Devops Build Pipelines. After Building the solution, I am trying to delete a specific DLL from the bin folder which works locally but not in the build pipeline.

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <PostBuildEvent>
     cd $(TargetDir)
     del Sample.dll
   </PostBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
```

**Build Solution Definition**

```
steps:
- task: VSBuild@1   displayName: 'Build solution'   inputs:
    solution: '$(Parameters.solution)'
    vsVersion: 15.0
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=false /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\\" /p:Configuration=Release'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
    maximumCpuCount: true
```

**Delete**

```
steps:
- task: DeleteFiles@1
  displayName: 'Delete files from $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    Contents: |
     \Sage.Common.LinqBridge*\
     \Sage.Common.LinqBridge.dll*\
```

**Publish**

```
steps:
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
  inputs:
    ArtifactName: '$(Parameters.ArtifactName)'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

**Solution:**
Thank you @Levi Lu-MSFT in helping me with the solution.

In the delete task, changing the delete pattern worked. For [reference](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fnmatch.3.html),

```
steps: 
- task: DeleteFiles@1 
displayName: 'Delete files from $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)' 
inputs: 
SourceFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)' 
Contents: '**\Sage.Common.LinqBridge.dll'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Remove a DLL from the bin folder in the Build Pipeline

I have created a sample to test, and it works fine on my side.

To resolve this issue, I would like provide following trouleshootings:

1. Check the build log, to found out if the `PostBuildEvent` is executed successfully.
2. Make sure you have specify the correct MSBuild arguments in the build task, like: `/property:Configuration=Release`:

   [image]
3. If you are using the private agent, make sure you have permission to delete file from the private agent. Or you can test it with hosted agent.

**Update:**

According to the error log, we could to know you are publishing the project and delete the one .dll file in the post build event.

If you check the log, you will find MSBuild get the files from the folder `obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin` rather than `bin` folder. That is the reason why the Sage.Common.LinqBridge.dll still exists after you delete it.

Check the log:

```
Adding file (d:\a\8\s\xx\xxx\xxx\xxx\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Sage.Common.LinqBridge.dll)
```

And you could not delete that file in the .zip by the delete task.

To resolve this issue, you could set `Copy Local` to `False` for that dll file.

**Update2:**

After talk with mbharanidharan88, found the reason for this issue is that not use correct syntax in the contents in the delete task.

To delete the file only in the bin folder, we could use the following syntax:

```
**\bin\Sage.Common.LinqBridge.dll
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: PostBuildEvent executed the `del` command but the same dll still exists in the Artifacts directory?

Comment: @mbharanidharan88, That's weird. Could you please share the log about your build task and the build definition about your copy and publish build task?

Comment: Here are the [logs](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/790baf2af46ea7430bcb3564e24bf2cb20190826080212/c1ab4e)

Comment: Also updated the question with the build definition

Comment: @mbharanidharan88, Thanks for your quick reply. I have checked you build log and find the reason for this issue, you can check the updated answer for some more details.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not referring the dll through project reference instead I've configured the binding redirect and pointed to the package folder where that dll exist.The reason Sage.Common.LinqBridge.dll is automatically copied to the bin folder is the other DLL which uses it somehow resolving it automatically. So the only way for me is to delete it from the bin folder after the build. Any other alternatives please?

Comment: @mbharanidharan88, Do you need it for your current project? If not, you can delete it before the build starting. If not, I don't have a better way to remove it in the process of publishing at this moment.

Comment: I need that dll only when the project run and only on a fewer modules but the actual thing is that dll is copied only after building the project

Comment: @mbharanidharan88, Got it. This is indeed a tricky issue. My workaround is unzip the Artifact: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43764661/extract-zip-artifact-as-part-of-azure-app-service-deploy, then delete the file, then zip it and publish build Artifact.

Comment: It's not zip already, `/p:PackageAsSingleFile=false` and I am trying to delete from the folder only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198471/discussion-between-levi-lu-msft-and-mbharanidharan88).