# App Service does not run if Azure DevOps deployment to Azure App Service

Tags: azure

I setup Continuous Deployment on Azure Devops to deploy .netCore app to Azure.

On Azure Devops, I set "Run From Package" as deployment method.
On Azure App service, I set application settings "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE = 1"

Below is deployment log:

```
2021-05-18T14:30:25.8791622Z ##[section]Starting: Deploy Azure App Service
2021-05-18T14:30:25.8885471Z ==============================================================================
2021-05-18T14:30:25.8885925Z Task         : Azure App Service deploy
2021-05-18T14:30:25.8886265Z Description  : Deploy to Azure App Service a web, mobile, or API app using Docker, Java, .NET, .NET Core, Node.js, PHP, Python, or Ruby
2021-05-18T14:30:25.8886588Z Version      : 4.184.4
2021-05-18T14:30:25.8886793Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2021-05-18T14:30:25.8887039Z Help         : https://aka.ms/azureappservicetroubleshooting
2021-05-18T14:30:25.8887334Z ==============================================================================
2021-05-18T14:30:26.2964626Z Got service connection details for Azure App Service:'<myappname>'
2021-05-18T14:30:28.4979467Z Trying to update App Service Application settings. Data: {"WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE":"1"}
2021-05-18T14:30:28.7373901Z App Service Application settings are already present.
2021-05-18T14:30:29.1236558Z Package deployment using ZIP Deploy initiated.
2021-05-18T14:30:32.4259162Z Successfully deployed web package to App Service.
2021-05-18T14:30:32.4310502Z NOTE: Run From Package makes wwwroot read-only, so you will receive an error when writing files to this directory.
2021-05-18T14:30:33.3237075Z App Service Application URL: http://<myappname>.azurewebsites.net
2021-05-18T14:30:33.3331472Z ##[section]Finishing: Deploy Azure App Service
```

However if I visit http://myappname.azurewebsites.net  , it only shows one line text "You do not have permission to view this directory or page."

Check "C:\home\site\wwwroot" on Azure, I see myappname.zip is there.

Check "C:\home\data\SitePackages" on Azure

```
05/18/2021  01:00 PM        13,998,003 20210518130026.zip
05/18/2021  01:39 PM        13,997,972 20210518133935.zip
05/18/2021  01:53 PM        13,998,047 20210518135341.zip
05/18/2021  02:30 PM        13,997,891 20210518143029.zip
05/18/2021  02:30 PM                18 packagename.txt
```

Since I configured "Run From Package" and the mynameapp.zip does exist, why the website does not load the page?

Could someone help me out please?

Comment: You should extract your zip file to wwwroot folder. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43764661/extract-zip-artifact-as-part-of-azure-app-service-deploy

Comment: Thank you. I think since I select "Run From Package", it should not be extracted again. However I workaround it by setting app setting WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE = 0 during publish.