# DevOps Release Pipeline ZIP file into Azure Function App Deployment

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines

1. When i'm trying to do azure devops release pipeline using function i'm getting bellow issues.
2. copying and archive taskes i'm using
3. In the azure function app deploy taks i'm using zip and "i configured additational deployment as "zip deploy" and "zip deploy with run from package"
4. I configured WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE = 1 , WEBSITE_WEBDEPLOY_USE_SCM = true

1111-01-01T12:48:18.7320311Z ##[section]Starting: Azure Function App Deploy: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
1111-01-01T12:48:18.7434752Z ==============================================================================
1111-01-01T12:48:18.7434920Z Task         : Azure Functions Deploy
1111-01-01T12:48:18.7434992Z Description  : Update a function app with .NET, Python, JavaScript, PowerShell, Java based web applications
1111-01-01T12:48:18.7435114Z Version      : 2.218.1
1111-01-01T12:48:18.7435174Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
1111-01-01T12:48:18.7435265Z Help         : https://aka.ms/azurefunctiontroubleshooting
1111-01-01T12:48:18.7435348Z ==============================================================================
1111-01-01T12:48:19.9008284Z Got service connection details for Azure App Service:'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
1111-01-01T12:48:21.1672101Z (node:2688) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
1111-01-01T12:48:32.5957978Z Trying to update App Service Application settings. Data: {"WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE":"1"}
1111-01-01T12:48:32.5958428Z Deleting App Service Application settings. Data: ["WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_ZIP"]
1111-01-01T12:48:32.5959252Z App Service Application settings are already present.
1111-01-01T12:51:10.9128451Z Validating deployment package for functions app before Zip Deploy
1111-01-01T13:09:06.0866760Z Package deployment using ZIP Deploy initiated.
1111-01-01T13:27:01.3376109Z ##[error]Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
1111-01-01T13:27:01.3391569Z ##[error]To debug further please check Kudu stack trace URL : https://$XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:***@XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.scm.yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyapps.com/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace
1111-01-01T13:27:01.3393869Z ##[error]Error: Error: Failed to deploy web package to App Service. Error: connect ETIMEDOUT x.x.x.x:443
1111-01-01T13:27:02.7308381Z Successfully added release annotation to the Application Insight : XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
1111-01-01T13:27:03.5861517Z App Service Application URL: https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyapps.com
1111-01-01T13:27:03.6006868Z ##[section]Finishing: Azure Function App Deploy: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Answer (score 0):

I tried the steps below to deploy Azure Functions with Azure DevOps pipeline.

Task 1:-

***Created a build Pipeline by archiving files and Publish Artifact :-***

Yaml pipeline script:-

```yaml
# Starter pipeline

# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.

# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:

# https://aka.ms/yaml

  

trigger:

- master

  

pool:

vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

  

steps:

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2

inputs:

command: 'build'

projects: '**/*.csproj'

arguments: '--output $(Build.BinariesDirectory)/publish_output --configuration Release'

  

- task: ArchiveFiles@2

inputs:

rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)/publish_output'

includeRootFolder: false

archiveType: 'zip'

archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'

replaceExistingArchive: true

  

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1

inputs:

PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

ArtifactName: 'drop'

publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Build task was successful and I received my Published Artifact like below:-

[image]

[image]

Task 2:-

***Created a release pipeline to Deploy Function app to Azure:-***

**Added the Build artifact in the Release pipeline** like below:-

[image]

[image]

**Added Environment Variable set to Dev**

[image]

**In Azure functions Task selected Azure function app and valid subscription.**

[image]

Added **Environment Variable in App settings.**

[image]

[image]

***Now, I created the release and function got deployed in Function app like below:-***

[image]

**Portal:-**

[image]

Additionally, I visited my function app > Advance tool > Tools > ZipDeployUI like below:-

[image]

*The error connection time out might occur, Due to the poor network, firewall or a transient issue which can be fixed by retrying the deployment with correct steps. To get more insights check your kudu trace url in the error code.*

Comment: Thanks Siddhesh,
I have tried same thing but I'm getting same exception.

Comment: Did you follow all the steps as mentioned above? Also, Which app service tier is your function app created in?

Comment: Isolated I1 App Service plan

Comment: Did you check your kudu trace url ? https://$XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:***@XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.scm.yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyapps.com/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace 1111-01-01T13:27:01.3393869Z Any insights there?

Comment: @Dinesh Did you try to Redeploy the function app by following the solution here? In the Function App, go to the "Deployment Center" blade, and click on the "Disconnect" button on top.
After that re-run the release pipeline. Reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/382358/when-deploy-functionapp-to-slot-)-error-package-de

Comment: @Dinesh Also, did you try to keep your app settings as WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE = 0 and then tried deploying your app again? Refer the comment in this post here:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67588665/app-service-does-not-run-if-azure-devops-deployment-to-azure-app-service