# Azure Python Functions requirements.txt ignored when deployed from DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

I'm trying to deploy a handful of Python functions into my consumption plan based Function App using Azure DevOps YAML pipeline.

Despite following all the advice found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/recover-python-functions?tabs=manual%2Cbash&pivots=python-mode-configuration#enable-remote-build

I was still unable to:
(a) See why the requirements.txt in the root of the project was being ignored and
(b) Work out why, when I download my package from the URL provided at the APPLICATION_SETTINGS -> WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE variable there was in fact no .python_packages directory there at all.

This was despite setting SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT and ENABLE_ORYX_BUILD to True.

After hours of scrabbling around I eventually discovered a potential solution, which was to install the dependencies right there in the DevOps pipeline with:

```yaml
steps:
  - task: UsePythonVersion@0
    displayName: "Use Python 3.10"
    inputs:
      versionSpec: 3.10
    - bash: |
        pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      displayName: "Install application dependencies"
```

Prior to then creating and publishing the archive, which is then consumed by the AzureFunctionApp@2 action to deploy it.

Is this the correct way to accomplish this? The Python Functions documentation seems to suggest that the requirements.txt should be processed during the build, but it absolutely is not.

Where I am stuck is in trying to understand what that step is actually doing. Am I correct in saying it is installing the dependencies into the Python instance on the DevOps Agent just for the purposes of the agents own .python_packages folder, post install, to be copied into the artifact which is then deployed? Is that the case?

Fundamentally, my question is: Isn't there a better way?

Thanks!

Comment: is the `requirements.txt` file available in your root directory in your repo?

Comment: Yes, it categorically is.

Comment: Could you please share your root directory structure?

Comment: If you use a MS-hosted agent, you will get a brand new machine every time you run the pipeline. You need to run pip install -r ./requirements.txt to get the modules and packages required by your project. It's suggested that you could follow the steps in this doc [Example YAML build pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-azure-devops?tabs=python%2Cyaml&pivots=v1#tabpanel_3_python) to build and deploy your function app.

Comment: @ZiyangLiu-MSFT
Thanks for this. Is it possible the documentation could be improved by mentioning this in the context of the application settings SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT and ENABLE_ORYX_BUILD which seemed to suggest the function would be built during the deployment (from DevOps). Surely this process could be simplified for Python users?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this the correct way to accomplish this? The Python Functions documentation seems to suggest that the requirements.txt should be processed during the build, but it absolutely is not.

Yes, The requirements.txt packages needs to be installed in the DevOps agent and then the build artifact with the packages are deployed to the Function app for the Function Trigger to work. Even the Default Azure DevOps yaml code to Deploy the Python Function has separate pip install step to install packages. Refer below:-

I have used the Template below and selected my Function app and path set to - **`$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`**

**My Azure DevOps yaml script:-**

[image]

```yaml
trigger:
- master

variables:
  
  azureSubscription: 'xxxxxxxxxx354dd'

  # Function app name
  functionAppName: 'siliconfunc76'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

  # Working Directory
  workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage

  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - bash: |
        if [ -f extensions.csproj ]
        then
            dotnet build extensions.csproj --runtime ubuntu.16.04-x64 --output ./bin
        fi
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      displayName: 'Build extensions'

    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      displayName: 'Use Python 3.10'
      inputs:
        versionSpec: 3.10 # Functions V2 supports Python 3.6 as of today

    - bash: |
        pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      displayName: 'Install application dependencies'

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(workingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()

  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: 'development'
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:

          steps:
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure functions app deploy'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
              appType: functionAppLinux
              appName: $(functionAppName)
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
```

**Output:-**

All the package dependencies are installed in the Build step where Function is built on Azure DevOps agent like below:-

[image]

Those packages are Archived as an artifact like below:-

[image]

Then the Archived folder is published as an Artifact like below:-

[image]

In the next stage those Published artifact is Downloaded and Deployed in the Function App like below:-

[image]

[image]

**Above method is the Ideal and efficient method for now to Deploy the Function app**.

- You can only build the Function app with the Build step and use Release pipeline to Deploy the Function App via Release Refer my [SO thread answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75877443/devops-release-pipeline-zip-file-into-azure-function-app-deployment/75884713#75884713) for the same.
- Alternatively you can Refer My YAML script from this [SO thread answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77148969/azure-function-publish-reduce-scm-environment-setting-timout-duration/77215510#77215510) where I have utilized
  **`func azure functionapp publish functionappname --python`**  And installed the dependencies with **`pip install`** in the same build step.
- To Deploy FunctionV2 using Azure DevOps refer my [SO thread answer3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76559759/azure-functions-python-programming-model-v2-1-found-0-loaded/76562032#76562032).

Comment: Thank you so much. What a sensational answer! Incredibly helpful and I'm sure will be of great use to others. You are a credit to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Somehow it still tries to do the pip install, how can i prevent it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77571322/how-to-skip-build-download-dependencies-on-azure-devops-pipeline-on-python