# How to Deploy Python Code from Azure Repository to Azure Function(Linux Based) App using Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines, azure-durable-functions, azure-deployment

I have Durable Function written in Python 3.10 available in Azure Repository, I want to Build and Deploy a function to Azure Function App (Linux Based).

**I've tried with below pipeline configuration which deploy functions    to azure function app but it gives 500 Error when we use. Although If  I deploy this same code using VS Code manually, it works fine as    expected.**

- **Function App :**  OS: Linux Runtime Stack : Python - 3.10
- **Code** Located in Azure Repos

**Requirement : Need to Deploy Durable Function to Azure Function App using Azure Pipelines.**

[Image_Repository-Code Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRn7V.png)

**Configured Pipeline Code**

````
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  displayName: 'Use Python 3.10'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 3.10

steps:
- script: |
   python -m venv antenv
   source antenv/bin/activate
   # Upgrade pip
   python -m pip install --upgrade pip
   
   # Verify that pip is up to date
   pip --version
   
   pip install -r $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/[FOLDER1_ReposReference]/requirements.txt
  displayName: 'Command Line Script'
  
steps:
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/[FOLDER1_ReposReference]'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/[FOLDER1_ReposReference]'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/durable_function.zip'
    
steps:
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/durable_function.zip'
    
steps:
- task: AzureFunctionApp@2
  displayName: Deploy
  inputs:
    connectedServiceNameARM: 'SUBSCRIPTION_ID'
    appType: functionAppLinux
    appName: 'functionapp-name'
    package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/*.zip'
    runtimeStack: 'PYTHON|3.10'```
````

Comment: According to your description, you did not encounter any errors in the pipeline, right? I noticed that you have published the zip file to the artifact. You can download the zip file manually and check if the contents are correct. Then try to use one of the methods [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push) to manually deploy the zip file and see if you will encounter the same problem. These steps can narrow down the problem and identify which part the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

In order to Deploy Azure Function to Azure Function App  successfully from Azure Devops YAML pipeline, Refer below:-

**My Azure Repository with sample Function:-**

[image]

**Now, Select Set up build and select the Default Template like below:-**

[image]

In the Pop up window Select Your subscription and click continue > Sign in to your account and select your Linux Function app like below:-

[image]

***DevOps YAML* pipeline generated like below, Change Default python version to 3.10:-**

```yaml
trigger:
- master

variables:
  
  azureSubscription: 'xxxx-9fe1-00dc49fd1540'

  # Function app name
  functionAppName: 'siliconfunc63'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

  # Working Directory
  workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage

  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - bash: |
        if [ -f extensions.csproj ]
        then
            dotnet build extensions.csproj --runtime ubuntu.16.04-x64 --output ./bin
        fi
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      displayName: 'Build extensions'

    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      displayName: 'Use Python 3.10'
      inputs:
        versionSpec: 3.10 

    - bash: |
        pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      displayName: 'Install application dependencies'

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(workingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()

  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: 'development'
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:

          steps:
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure functions app deploy'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
              appType: functionAppLinux
              appName: $(functionAppName)
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

Refer my SO thread answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77305335/azure-python-functions-requirements-txt-ignored-when-deployed-from-devops/77307229#77307229) for more details on deploying Function via Devops.