# How to skip build/download dependencies on Azure DevOps pipeline on python

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

I am trying to deploy an application with azure devops to azure function. My libraries cannot be installed from azure, since it has no public access.

So i installed all the dependencies into the .zip.

But somehow the deployer still tries to install pip dependencies. How do I stop it from doing the `pip install`?

Here is my config:

```yaml
trigger:
- main
variables:
  workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'

steps:
  - task: UsePythonVersion@0
    displayName: 'Use Python 3.11'
    inputs:
      versionSpec: 3.11
  - bash: |
      pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt
    workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
    displayName: 'Install application dependencies'
  - task: ArchiveFiles@2
    displayName: 'Generate ZIP'
    inputs:
      rootFolderOrFile: '$(workingDirectory)'
      includeRootFolder: false
      archiveType: zip
      archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip

  - publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
    artifact: drop

  - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
    displayName: Azure Function App Deploy
    inputs:
      appType: 'functionAppLinux'
      deployToSlotOrASE: true
      DeploymentType: 'zipDeploy'
      packageForLinux: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
      runtimeStack: 'PYTHON|3.11'
```

Comment: This post was my inspiration, but somehow there is and issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77305335/azure-python-functions-requirements-txt-ignored-when-deployed-from-devops

Comment: SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT:true > Is this setting applied?

Comment: cannot find this parameter in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-rm-web-app-deployment-v4?view=azure-pipelines, where is it set?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/fZJy77x.png You need to set it in the Functions App> Configuration settings.

Comment: will try, thanks :)

Comment: Shouldn't the value of the app setting `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT` as `false`? referred to link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#scm_do_build_during_deployment

Comment: @wadezhou-MSFT As the deployment is done as zip, It needs to be set to true refer here - https://azureossd.github.io/2022/11/24/Python-on-Linux-App-Service-and-ModuleNotFound-Errors/#:~:text=If%20you%20are%20attempting%20a%20Zip%20Deploy%20%28without,is%20included%20in%20the%20zip%20file%20being%20deployed.

Comment: yes, somehow this works, all uploads and all fine now, no build, but also no function and no files inside, but pipline looks good, will update if i get it running :D

Comment: but with the `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT` to `true` it does try to do the pip install all the time from oryx

Answer (score 1):

You can add **`SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT:true`** setting in your Azure Function App.  As it avoids any module specific error and helps in remote build while zip deployment.

[image]

***And if the dependencies are already installed, Remove the pip install step itself and perform the Deployment like below:-***

```yaml
trigger:
- main

variables:
  
  azureSubscription: 'xxxxxxx6611762'

  
  functionAppName: 'functionpython87'

  
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

 
  workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage

  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - bash: |
        if [ -f extensions.csproj ]
        then
            dotnet build extensions.csproj --runtime ubuntu.16.04-x64 --output ./bin
        fi
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      displayName: 'Build extensions'

    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      displayName: 'Use Python 3.10'
      inputs:
        versionSpec: 3.10 

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(workingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()

  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: 'development'
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:

          steps:
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure functions app deploy'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
              appType: functionAppLinux
              appName: $(functionAppName)
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

*For Functions to be visible, Make sure you have the same settings as below:-*

```json
[
  {
    "name": "APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING",
    "value": "InstrumentationKey=68f4bced-7c86-45b1-a7b3-73d5fe9476ea;IngestionEndpoint=https://ukwest-0.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://ukwest.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
    "value": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=valleyrg78984ec;AccountKey=xxxxxOdUH2g==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
    "value": "~4",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME",
    "value": "python",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT",
    "value": "true",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING",
    "value": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=valleyrg78984ec;AccountKey=xxxxxtOdUH2g==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE",
    "value": "functionpython8781c8",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "WEBSITE_ENABLE_SYNC_UPDATE_SITE",
    "value": "false",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE",
    "value": "https://valleyrg78984ec.blob.core.windows.net/azure-pipelines-deploy/package_1701270611011.zip?st=xxxxCC1%2BrN4g%3D",
    "slotSetting": false
  }
]
```

[image]